# How do Install and use packages from Packagist?

Tags: composer

I would like to install use kamermans/guzzle-oauth2-subscriber in my Drupal 8 build.

I ran `composer require kamermans/guzzle-oauth2-subscriber` which put the package in mysite/vendor/kamermans.

The module is installed on mysite/docroot/modules/custom/scheduleapi.

The example code from Kamerman uses the following lines.

```
use kamermans\OAuth2\GrantType\AuthorizationCode;
use kamermans\OAuth2\GrantType\RefreshToken;
```

Clearly my module knows nothing about kamermans.

How do I access files and libraries that Composer puts into the vendor directory?

Comment: If it follows PSR-4, your module imports those classes via the “use” statement, no different than when you see “use Drupal\...”

Comment: Is that simple? :) 

Thanks @kevin I will see how far I get.